# Was the Quantum Circuit Attribute "iden" renamed?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm going through some older tutorials for my employer and everything seems to be working fine except the "iden" attribute. The error is listed below. I assume the name was changed but I don't know what it was changed to, and I don't know how to find out.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-fff169415f56> in <module>
      4 hello_qubit = QuantumCircuit(q)
      5 
----> 6 hello_qubit.iden(q[0])
      7 
      8 job = execute(hello_qubit, S_simulator)

AttributeError: 'QuantumCircuit' object has no attribute 'iden' '''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is called `id`:

```
from qiskit import *

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.id(0)
print(circuit)
```

```
     ┌───┐
q_0: ┤ I ├
     └───┘
```

If you want to implement a delay consider using `delay`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `QuantumCircuit.iden()` method was [deprecated](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#release-notes-0-13-0-deprecation-notes) in the qiskit-terra 0.13.0 release (qiskit 0.18.0) and removed in qiskit-terra 0.16.0 (qiskit 0.23.0): https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#release-notes-0-16-0-upgrade-notes

It was replaced with the `i()` or `id()`. So you can just replace `iden()` with either one of those.